# How is the following output derived? What is the value of '2'?

Tags: java

I tried running this  program but I never understood how this result turned up...I tried to add the ASCII value of B to 2 and that would have made the output 68 but the actual answer is completely different....

```
char a = 'B',b='2'; into c= a+b; System.out.println(c);.
```

Output:116

I don't understand how is this even coming??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `'B'` is ascii 66, `'2'` is ascii 50 => 66 + 50 + 116 . `char`s are not strings.

Comment: To know what's the value of `'2'`, just do `System.out.println((int)'2')`. Easy as that.

Answer (score 3):

here `b` is character '2'. So the `ASCII` value used for that is `50`. and `ASCII` value of 'B' is `66`. So the total is 116.